# Where am I hitting the invisible SD card cache?

Tags: linux, usb, removable-storage

I'm trying to clear an SD card connected via a USB dongle.

Here's what I do:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=$((1024*4))
dd: error writing '/dev/sdb': No space left on device
1002267+0 records in
1002266+0 records out
4105281536 bytes (4.1 GB, 3.8 GiB) copied, 2.10549 s, 1.9 GB/s
```

The weird things I see are: This is an SD HC I card, so the transfer should never reach 1.9GB/s. The card is 16GB and correctly reports as such in `dmesg`.

Ok, let's check it's written:

```
# head -c 4105281536 /dev/zero | sha1sum 
a1750724bfbf0ada57d986f16b26e789a6c61a1d  -
(reverse-i-search)`': ^C
# head -c 4105281536 /dev/sdb | sha1sum
a1750724bfbf0ada57d986f16b26e789a6c61a1d  -
```

Seems ok. But when I plug is out and in again, it magically has the same filesystem available as before.
When I mount them and change the files, the modification is also persisted, even though the `sha1sum` still shows it as zeros.

The device is definitely `/dev/sdb`:

```
[ 9895.437518] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device        PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 9895.439248] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 30318592 512-byte logical blocks: (15.5 GB/14.5 GiB)
[ 9895.439398] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 9895.439404] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 9895.439557] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 9895.439564] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 9895.441922]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[ 9895.443517] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

What's happening here?

Running on kernel `4.20.3`.

Answer (score 1):

I notice `dd` it only copies 3.8 GiB when the drive is 14.5 GiB.  So what you're writing to is most likely not the sd card.  Unplug the SD card and then check `ls -lh /dev/sdb`.

I suspect you have accidentally created a regular file on `/dev` called `/dev/sdb`.  Since `/dev` is a ram disk it explains why you can write to it at 2GBps

When you've finished your `dd` command, remember to `sync` just in case. This will tell the kernel to flush any cache it has.